# How to get the dimensions of a rectangle?

Tags: geometry, size

Suppose I create a `Rectangle` of dimensions 1 and 3. Is there any function in Mathematica that I can use to recover the dimensions of the original rectangle? If there is no such a function, is there a way of recovering the dimensions?

Answer (score 7):

I assume you mean from a `Graphics` object. If so, something like:

```
Cases[g, Rectangle[x___] :> {x}, 2]
```

where `g` is the graphics object will return a list of coordinates from which dimensions can be derived.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you very much

Comment: Worth to add `Normal` on `g` in case of `GraphicsComplex`.

Answer (score 2):

To deal with `Rectangle`s with a single or no argument, we need to change the replacement rule in ciao's answer.

```
ClearAll[rectangleArgs]
rectangleArgs = Cases[Normal@#, 
    Rectangle[x___] :> If[Length[{x}] === 1, {x, x + {1, 1}}, {x}], 2] &;

g = Graphics[{Opacity[.5], Hue[RandomReal[]], Rectangle[], 
   Hue[RandomReal[]], Rectangle[{1, 1}], 
   Hue[RandomReal[]], Disk[RandomReal[2, {2}], .5], 
   Hue[RandomReal[]], Rectangle[{2, 0}, {3, 2}]}]
```

[image]

```
rectangleArgs@g
```

> {{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}, {{2, 0}, {3, 2}}}